# Java Collection Issue

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Ok so I have a small lab test coming up and the subject is pretty hard for me. I managed to get an example subject from someone who already took it but I'm having issues solving it. The subject is at follows:

> Create class Apartment(int nr, String orientation) and have a class LuxuryApartment that inherits from class Apartment and also has an attribute surface of type Float.

This is pretty straightforward I guess, no issues here.

> Create class MyLinkedList which extends the class LinkedList so you can store Apartment type objects in it. Add a method called sortByOrientation() which will sort the apartments alphabetically by their orientation, using a comparator defined as a normal inner class.

Here is where I'm having a bit of trouble. I can create my class MyLinkedList but I don't understand how the method sortByOrientation() should look like.

> Create a test program which initializes a MyLinkedList. Add 3 apartments and 3 LuxuryApartments. Print the list, sort the list using the sortByOrientation() method and print the list using an iterator.

How can I add LuxuryApartments to a MyLinkedList if they said earlier I should make the class so that I can only store apartments?

> Move the apartments which aren't luxury into a LinkedList and the luxury ones into a LinkedList. Create a method that lists the apartments and the luxury apartments.

I guess this isn't hard, but what do they mean by move? Do I take my apartments from the aforementioned MyLinkedList?

Can someone give me a few pointers with this exercise? I'm really lost here. Sorry if my question is stupid/doesn't respect guidelines/etc. but I'm really out of ideas on how to get this exercise going.

The Apartment class - im not sure if it needs to implement the Comparable interface, as I said, i'm pretty bad with Java at the moment

```
public class Apartament implements Comparable<Apartament>{
    private int nr;
    private String orientare;
    public int getNr() {
        return nr;
    }
    public void setNr(int nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }
    public String getOrientare() {
        return orientare;
    }
    public void setOrientare(String orientare) {
        this.orientare = orientare;
    }

    public Apartament(int nr, String orientare){
        this.nr=nr;
        this.orientare=orientare;
    }
    public int compareTo(Apartament ap){
        return ap.orientare.compareTo(this.orientare);
    }
}
```

My LuxuryApartment class which inherits from my Apartment class

```
public class ApartamentLux extends Apartament{
    private float suprafata;

    public float getSuprafata() {
        return suprafata;
    }

    public void setSuprafata(float suprafata) {
        this.suprafata = suprafata;
    }

    public ApartamentLux(int n, String o, float suprafata){
        super(n,o);
        this.suprafata=suprafata;
    }
}
```

This is where I'm really lost, can't seem to get this to work.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList<Apartament>{
    public MyLinkedList(){
        super();
    }
    private static class OrComp implements Comparator<String>{
        public int compare(String s1, String s2){
            if(s1.compareTo(s2)<0)
                return 1;
            else return 0;
        }


    public void sortByOrientare(OrComp list){
        list.sort(new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2){
                return Collator.getInstance().compare(s1, s2);
            }
        });

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @nhouser9 it's not homework, I'm going to add my poor attempt at solving it now though

Comment: Regarding point 3. If you understand inheritance, then a LuxuryApartment is a type of Apartment. Your List can contain an Apartment and any thing that extends from an Apartment.

Comment: this might enlighten you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html as well

Comment: OrComp is redundant and incomplete. The sortByOrientare method should not accept a parameter, and should simply call `this.sort()` with a `Comparator<Apartment>` that compares `a.getOrientare()` with `b.getOrientare()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your list class, you should be sorting the list (`this`) from the method. You've created an extra Comparator<String> that returns 0 when it should return -1, and tried to sort that.

You don't need to implement the Comparable interface since you're doing it this way, and anyway I believe you should use this.orientare.compareTo(other.orientare) rather than the other way around.

But using the custom method and comparator, which seems to be what the exercise is asking for, here's a simpler way to make that work.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList<Apartament> {
    public void sortByOrientare(){
        sort(new MyComparator());
    }
    class MyComparator extends Comparator<Apartament> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Apartament s1, Apartament s2){
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(s1.getOrientare(), s2.getOrientare());
        }
    }
}
```

Since ApartamentLux extends Apartament, instances of it can be added to your custom list. (Since they are also instances of Apartament)

It seems like you have everything else figured out, except splitting up the list. I'm guessing here, but I imagine what they want is something like this:

```
LinkedList<Apartament> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<Apartament> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
for(Apartament a : myList) {
    if(a instanceof ApartamentLux) {
        list2.add(a);
    } else {
        list1.add(a);
    }
}
```

Followed by printing out the list.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I really need to get studying and catch up with Java. One question though, what do they mean when they say my sortByOrientare method should "using a comparator defined as a normal inner class" ?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that requirement. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what they mean by "normal" inner class, my best guess is "not static".

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add LuxuryApartments to a MyLinkedList if they said earlier I should make the class so that I can only store apartments?

Since MyLinkedListtype can store Apartment type it can store LuxuryApartments as well since its a child class.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to use LinkedList<Object> at first, didn't know this was the case. Thank you!